# execute payment paypal flutter

Tags: flutter, web-applications, paypal

I am trying to implement paypal payments in a WebApp, but WebView is not compatible with the web.
i also tried dart: ui but without success.

```
//ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'paypal-html',
      (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString()
        ..height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString()
        ..src = checkoutUrl
        ..style.border = 'none');

SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'paypal-html'),
        ),
```

Do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webviews [are not supported by PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/info-security-guidelines/#link-donotuseawebviewtodisplaypaypalwebpageswithinyourapplication) for payment approval. A browser view mechanism with an address bar must be used (such as a Safari View Controller or Chrome Custom Tab)

Comment: how can i do it? URL Launcher Packege?

Comment: That might work, and the return URL would be somewhere in your app that then triggers capturing the order. You can use the v2/checkout/orders API from a server to create an order with an application_context -> return_url set in the request, which will have a web approval link in the response.  See the orders create API reference https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create